# Access iframe elements from injected content_script

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which injects a content_script which injects an iframe into the document, e.g.:

```
    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
    wrap.id = "myiframe-wrap";

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = "myiframe";
    iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html");
```

At some point of time I need to access one of the elements of myiframe from this content script. What is the best way to do it?

I currently try to call:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('some-id');
```

but, I'm getting cross origin issues.

Comment: This resolved bug might be a clue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=272373

Comment: please include your manifest.json - are you sure you have the permissions?